# Proposed proof of operator theory result

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Hi I am interested in checking my proposed solution to the following problem in Operator Theory: Please give me hints as to how to improve the proposed proof rather than the full correct solution.

**Question:** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital Banach Algebra.  Consider $\{a_{n}\}_{n} \subset \mathcal{A}$ where $a_{n} \to a \in \mathcal{A}$. Suppose that $\sigma(a_{n})$, $\sigma(a) \subset \Omega$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is an open set. Show that for any $f \in \text{hol}(\Omega)$ it follows that $f(a_{n}) \to f(a)$.

**Proposed proof:**

Choose $\Gamma$ such that winding number $\text{ind}_{\Gamma}(\lambda) = 1$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(a_{n}) \cup \sigma(a)$ and $\{ z : \text{ind}_{\Gamma}(z) \neq 0 \} \subset \Omega$.

In the following I use that $f(z)\big((z-a_{n})^{-1}-(z-a)^{-1}\big)$ is continuous on compact set $\Gamma$ and therefore bounded and also I use the *second resolvent identity* which states that $(z-a_{n})^{-1}-(z-a)^{-1} = (z-a_{n})^{-1}(a_{n}-a)(z-a)^{-1}$.

$$
\begin{align}
0 \leq \|f(a_{n})- f(a)\| &= \bigg\| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma}f(z)\big((z-a_{n})^{-1}-(z-a)^{-1}\big)dz\bigg\|
\\& = \bigg\|\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma}f(z)(z-a_{n})^{-1}(a_{n}-a)(z-a)^{-1}dz\bigg\| 
\\& \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi }\bigg(\sup_{z \in \Gamma} \bigg\| f(z)(z-a_{n})^{-1}(a_{n}-a)(z-a)^{-1}\bigg\| \bigg\| \Gamma \bigg\|\bigg)
\\& \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi }\bigg(\sup_{z \in \Gamma} \bigg\| f(z)(z-a_{n})^{-1}\bigg\| \bigg\|(a_{n}-a)\bigg\| \bigg\|(z-a)^{-1}\bigg\| \bigg\| \Gamma \bigg\|\bigg) \to 0
\end{align}
$$ 
Therefore $f(a_{n}) \to f(a)$ in $\mathcal{A}$.  $\square$

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Seems OK, apart from the fact that you have a pure imaginary number greater or equal to a real number. You want to delete the $i$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks for your response. Oh you mean drop the $i$ since $|\frac{1}{2 \pi i}| = \frac{1}{2 \pi}$?

Comment: - Yes, precisely.